# Divergent Thinking In Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I started to learn, explore and implement different features of cucumber to fulfill the overcome ambiguous requirements and misunderstandings i had been experiencing in Non-Cucumber based framework in my organization and have been enjoying cucumber a lot. I always love to spend my time exploring something new in cucumber and feature file structure & the way we shall document our requirements in feature file matters a lot to me and I always love to come up with better documented requirements in feature file.

Last week, i came to know about something known as "Divergent Thinking In Cucumber" but i could not get much about it and nothing much on net about it other side.

Can someone help us to understand what is Divergent Thinking In Cucumber.

Comment: https://cucumber.io/blog/2014/10/21/the-two-modes-of-thought-you-need-for-bdd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need both modes (divergent & convergent) of thought to do BDD: divergent thinking to explore the problem and discover scenarios, then convergent thinking to turn those examples into an executable specification and we can visualize these 2 concept in below image.

[image]